# How to pass object or data from one to another controller in spring-boot web application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to take a some of data from users' input and then I want to transfer these between `controllers`.But this transfer must be done in the background ***for security***. I don't want to send parameters on the URL.

I want to send the user object created in `page1` controller to `page2`.
I used the model method for this, but I was not successful.

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {
...
..
.

@GetMapping("/page1")
public String page1(Model model) {

    User user = new User();
    user.setName("TestName");
    user.setSurname("TestSurname");
    user.setMail("xyzabc@gmail.com");

    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "redirect:/page2";
}

@GetMapping("/page2")
public String page2(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model model) {

    System.out.println(user.toString());
    return "page2";
}

.
..
...
}
```

How do I transfer objects?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions for this question:

> Solution 1: Store object in `session`

Code example:

```
@GetMapping("/page1")
public String page1(Model model, HttpSession session) {
   ...

   session.setAttribute("user", user);
   return "redirect:/page2";
}

@GetMapping("/page2")
public String page2(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    User user = null;
    if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
        user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }
    return "page2";
}
```

> Solution 2: use forward instead of redirect

Code example:

```
@GetMapping("/page1")
public String page1(Model model) {
    ...
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "forward:/page2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either :

1. session

or

2)forward:/page2 instead of redirect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).